# How to create an object type based on keys/values of a const object in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I need to define a type based on a config object (`anObject`), which will be used in my code.

I wrote something like the following,

```
const anObject = {
  foo: ["a", "b", "c"],
  bar: ["d", "e", "f"],
} as const;

type aType =
  | { key: ""; value: [] }
  | { key: "foo"; value: ("a" | "b" | "c")[] }
  | { key: "bar"; value: ("d" | "e" | "f")[] };

const a: aType = { key: "", value: [] }; // No error
const b: aType = { key: "foo"; value: ["a", "b"] }; // No error
const c: aType = { key: "bar"; value: ["e", "f"] }; // No error
```

How to declare `aType` dynamically in TypeScript?

Comment: How open/locked down do you want it? I mean, on the face of it, `type aType = typeof anObject;` but I'm guessing that's too restrictive for what you're looking for. Should it only allow `foo` and `bar`? Should `foo` only allow `"a"`, `"b"`, and `"c"`? Only in that order, or another order? Same questions for `bar`. What people often do in these kinds of questions is show us some assignments that A) should work, and B) shouldn't work (and why). That's really helpful in answering them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worth using union here:

```js
const anObject = {
    foo: ["a", "b", "c"],
    bar: ["d", "e", "f"],
} as const;

type AnObject = typeof anObject;

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type AType = {
    [P in keyof AnObject]: {
        key: P,
        value: Array<AnObject[P][number]>
    }
}

type Default = { key: ""; value: [] }

type Result = Values<AType> | Default

const foo: Result = { key: "", value: [] }; // ok
const bar: Result = { key: "bar", value: ["d"] } // ok
```

Feel free to add any new keys to `anObject`. You don't need to make updates anywhere else

Please keep in mind, as @T.J Crowder said, there is no order in `value` property.
TS will allow different combinations of value: `[d,e] | [e, d] | [d]`.

If you want it in same order, just use this line: `value: AnObject[P]` in `AType` helper

Answer (score 0):

What about this code?

```
const anObject = {
    foo: ["a", "b", "c"],
    bar: ["d", "e", "f"],
} as const;

type aType = {
    key: keyof typeof anObject | "";
    value: typeof anObject[keyof typeof anObject][number][];
} & (
    | { key: ""; value: undefined[] }
    | { key: "foo"; value: typeof anObject["foo"][number][] }
    | { key: "bar"; value: typeof anObject["bar"][number][] }
    );

const foo: aType = { key: "", value: [] };
```

I simply added the undifined type, so that I don't get an TypeScript error. Solves that your problem?

And the second problem is a simple implementation error, because if you base your type on the config object sure your type must have all properties of it. So you have to chage your approach. If you can explain your needs more detailed I may be able to help you.

I know that this is very far-fetched now, but can it be that you wanted to something like this:

```
export interface MyConfiguration {
    foo?: ("a" | "b" | "c")[],
    bar?: ("d" | "e" | "f")[],
}

const DefaultMyConfiguration: MyConfiguration = {
    foo: ["b", "c"],
    bar: ["d"]
}

//In the middle of somewhere in your code you can now do this
let config: MyConfiguration
function myConstructor(config: MyConfiguration) {
    config = {...DefaultMyConfiguration, ...config}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to limit `value` with the respective value of `key` in `anObject`.

For example, when key = `"foo"`, value should be under the type `("a" | "b" | "c")[]`, when key = `"bar"`, value should be under the type `("d" | "e" | "f")[]`.

See the updated question for details.

Comment: I would also limit the array to be empty (length 0) if key = `""`. But `undefined[]` means accepting a variable length array filled with `undefined`.

Comment: see my updated answer. In my opinion that's impossible because TypeScript needs to know the dynamic value of the key to know the valid values of the value and I think that's too complicated for that TypeScript supports this. But I don't know exactly